# Android app always crashes

Tags: android, admob, ads

Can anyone please tell me what wrong?
The app always crashes on device SE xperia X10. maybe it's the way I'm embedding ADMOB.
It doesn't even show for a second. Any clues please?
Everything seems to be alright in the XML and the manifest.
Thank you

```
package com.taiic.template.admob;


import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.location.*;
import android.content.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class adMain extends Activity {

    Button addressButton;
    TextView locationText;
    TextView addressText;
    Location currentLocation;
    double currentLatitude;
    double currentLongitude;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);




    addressText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.addressText);
    locationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationText);
    addressButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addressButton);

    this.addressText.setText("ready");

    LocationManager locationManager = 
        (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updateLocation(location);
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(
                String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    this.addressButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            getAddress();
        }
    });
}

void getAddress(){
    try{
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = 
            gcd.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude,100);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++){
                Address address =  addresses.get(i);
                int maxIndex = address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();
                for (int x = 0; x <= maxIndex; x++ ){
                    result.append(address.getAddressLine(x));
                    result.append(",");
                }               
                result.append(address.getLocality());
                result.append(",");
                result.append(address.getPostalCode());
                result.append("\n\n");
            }
            addressText.setText(result.toString());
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        addressText.setText(ex.getMessage().toString());
    }
}

void updateLocation(Location location){
    currentLocation = location;
    currentLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
    currentLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
    locationText.setText(currentLatitude + ", " + currentLongitude);
}

AdView layout = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.setTesting(true);
layout.loadAd(adRequest); 
}
```

And here is the catlog

```
07-13 00:10:59.451: D/AndroidRuntime(3735): Shutting down VM
07-13 00:10:59.451: W/dalvikvm(3735): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.taiic.template.admob/com.taiic.template.admob.adMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1581)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at com.taiic.template.admob.adMain.<init>(adMain.java:102)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
07-13 00:10:59.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3735):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The log is pretty clear about what's going wrong:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
at com.taiic.template.admob.adMain.<init>(adMain.java:102)
```

In the class `adMain`, on line 102, you are trying to inflate a view that does not exist in the activity's layout:

```
AdView layout = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

So the question is: did you actually add an `AdView` view (with id `android:id="@+id/adView"`) to the layout defined in the `main.xml` file you're setting as content view on the activity? The error suggests you didn't.

Comment: And if he did define an AdView in XML, does it AdView have `android:id="adView"`?

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag: Good catch; theoretically he might've defined `android:id="@+id/adView"` in some other layout. On the other hand, the code snippet suggests he's still testing out enabling ads, so I'm guessing references aren't all over the place, yet. I'll add it to the answer, just in case.

Comment: If this answered your question, please consider marking it as such by marking the tick left of it. This way you keep your acceptance level up and it will be easier to find for others with similar problems.